# Why is derivative different

Tags: derivatives

$y^2 = (x-1)/ (x+1)$ implicates that derivative is $y'= 1/y(x+1)^2$. But if you eliminate denominator, then one obtains $y' = (1-y^2)/2y(x+1)$. Why is this different?

Comment: What do you mean "eliminate denominator?"

Comment: I got also $$y'=\frac{1}{y(x+1)^2}$$. What have you eliminated?

Comment: Do you mean "rationalize the denominator?"

Comment: Yes rationalize denominator then take derivative

Comment: Another words it becomes y^2(x+1) = (x-1) - and when I compute derivative it is y’= (1-y^2)/2y(x+1)

Comment: They are equal.